Security of encrypting whitened plaintext with ECB
Suppose you whiten plaintext with a weak stream cipher (that is not known-plaintext secure) such as the message/key schedule of SHA-2. Using key1 (ex. 512 bits for sha256 schedule).
Then encrypt the whitened plaintext with a block cipher in ECB mode (that is, no mode). Using key2 (ex. 256 bits for AES).
Would the result be secure? Authentication is out of scope.

Hint: I think you'd mainly look at the IND- part of IND-CPA.
